# How to stop touch response for flutter_webview's WebView when I touch a floating button

Tags: flutter

There is a `GestureDetector` above the `WebView`.

when I touch the `GestureDetector`, the `WebView` is also response touch event.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        WebView(
          initialUrl: url,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          child:Image.asset('.....'),
          onTap:(){
            //do something
          }
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

How Can I stop WebView's touch response when I tap the GestureDetector?

Comment: Do you want that `WebView` doesn't response for touch at all? That only `GestureDetector` responses?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky only `GestureDetector` responses

Comment: Than you can check my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thhink this is what you need. `AbsorbPointer` is absorbing all the touches and doesn't allow `WebView` to get them.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    AbsorbPointer(
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      child:Image.asset('.....'),
      onTap:(){
        //do something
      }
    )
  ],
);
```