# Facing issue with IgnorePointer while using with Webview

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview, flutter-ignore-pointer

I have a webview implemented in my flutter application which is wrapped by an Ignorepointer Widget. I am setting ignoring as true upon a condition to prevent touch events of webview.

But it is not working as expected, I am able to touch webview even if ignoring is true. This is observed only in IOS not in android.

Kindly provide me a solution.

I have also implemented absorbpointer instead of ignorepointer still this issue is replicating.

Code

IgnorePointer(
ignoring:true,
child:InAppWebview(
....
)
)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89956

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have given a sample code

Answer (score -1):

Try this soulution:

```dart
AbsorbPointer(child: WebView(...))
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900810/8923759

Comment: I have tried using AbsorbPointer but still the webview is getting touched.